# Strange POST data junk being returned

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, post

I'm writing a fairly basic commenting function for a site using post method to pass input values to a php file that performs the relevant mysql query.

The $.ajax part is as follows:

```
// AJAX URL ENCODING
$("#add").click(function() {  
        // POST COMMENT FORM VALUES
        var ajaxOpts = {  
        type: "post",  
        url: "includes/addComment.php",  
        data: "&author=" + $("#author").find("input").val() + "&email=" + $("#email").find("input").val() + "&comment=" + $("#leaveComment").find("textarea").val() + "&parent=<?php echo $vid_id; ?>",  
        success: function(data) {  

            // IMMEDIATE DISPLAY
            // Not relevant to this problem.

            // CLEAR TEXTAREA FOR NEXT COMMENT
            $("textarea").val('');  
        } 


        };  

    $.ajax(ajaxOpts);  
});
```

This is passed through to addcomment.php:

```
require('connection.php');    

//get POST data  
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["author"]); 
$email = strtolower(md5(trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"])))); 
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["comment"]);
$time = Date ('c');
$parent = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["parent"]));


//add new comment to database  
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments VALUES(' $name ',' $email ',' $comment ', ' $time ', ' $parent ')");
```

Everything works fine except that the mysql_query doesn't end up inserting any values into my database. After a bit of digging I found this:

[image: screen grab]

So i'm assuming my query isn't going ahead because the ' : ' bit of junk(?) data is throwing everything out?

I'm trying to figure out where this errant ' : ' has come from, anyone have any ideas?

P.S - Apologies for the length of this question, I've tried to narrow down possible culprits as much as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what happens if you remove the & from the front of &author?

normally the first data field doesn't have an &

```
data: "&author="
```

also as others have mentioned this would be a welcome addition

```
or die (mysql_error())
```

and its usually good practice to name your database columns on the insert 
otherwise you risk breaking the insert statement if you ever alter the table structure

```
insert into (colname1, colname2) values ('value1', 'value2')
```

Answer (score 3):

You dont have to do that URI encoding yourself. Read the documentation of jquery, the 'data' to be sent could be a map/json.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

change

```
data: "&author=" + $("#author").find("input").val() + "&email=" + $("#email").find("input").val() + "&comment=" + $("#leaveComment").find("textarea").val() + "&parent=<?php echo $vid_id; ?>"
```

into

```
{ author: 'something',email:'test' }
```

or more professionally

```
$("#testform").serialize() //here #("#testform") stands for a '<form>' tag
```

And try not to complicate the problem, start with some simple functions, use more echo() and alert() to debug.

Comment: Cheers for that! Simplifies things a million-fold!

Answer (score 0):

you can print_r($_POST) to see if the colon is really there.
secondly, while debugging it wouldn't hurt to throw an

```
or die (mysql_error())
```

at the end of your query. 
Without those two, it's hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

2 things :

- ajaxOpts variable is out of scope , you will have a error ( ajaxOpts is not defined)
- In you example, you miss }); at the end , you should check your JS validate too before checking your php script is working. If you have a JS error, the ajax call will not be called.

Comment: Oops! just noticed I lopped that off when I pasted in my code. Edited.